# ¿Cómo muestro el JSON de una consulta a MySql en php?

Tags: php, json

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
<?php
require("config/conf.php"); //El fichero donde se conecta a la base de datos
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$rawdata = array();

$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rawdata[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($rawdata);
?>
```

Por favor, que alguien me ayude el deploy es muy pronto y lo necesito urgentemente.

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el problema o error?

Comment: Que se muestra lo siguiente: [ ]

Comment: Puede que tu consulta no traiga datos. Prueba a poner un `var_dump($row);` dentro del `while`. Por cierto, ¿esa tabla `users` qué es, es una tabla que creaste tú o es la tabla `users` interna del SGBD? Si es lo segundo: ¿el usuario con el que estás conectado tiene privilegios de acceso para esa tabla? Considera depurar tu código como digo, con `var_dump` y considera ser más *pesimista* cuando programas, no hay ningún control de errores en tu código (programación optimista o ingenua) que produce códigos mal escritos, sin manejo de errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo este código, con control de errores, y evitando cosas innecesarias, como un contador `$i` dentro del bucle.

Considera que los SGBD tienen su propia tabla `users`, puede que el código falle debido a eso, sea lo que sea, lo verás con un código robusto. Ahí vamos:

```
<?php

    require("config/conf.php"); //El fichero donde se conecta a la base de datos
    /*
        OJO: declaramos el array aquí
    */
    $rawdata = array();
    
    /*
       1er error optimista: asumes que hay conexión
       pero nadie te asegura que la haya, por tanto, controla que hay
    */
    if ($conexion) {
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
        /*
            2do error optimista, asumías que la consulta funciona
            pero nada te asegura que funcione
        */
        if ($resultado) {
            /*
                3er error optimista, asumías que la consulta trae filas
                pero nada te asegura que traiga
            */
            if($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    //No necesitas un contador
                    $rawdata[] = $row;
                }
            } else {
                $rawdata['error']='No se encontraron filas';
            }
        } else {
            $rawdata['error']=sprintf('Error en la consulta: %s',$conexion->error);
        }
    } else {
        $rawdata['error']='No hay conexión';
    }
    echo json_encode($rawdata);

?>
```

Como ves, hemos escrito un programa robusto, que devolverá siempre un resultado, con error, indicando lo que haya fallado, sea con los datos. *¡Es un código más largo, gritará alguno!* Pues sí, pero así debe ser, una de las principales tareas de un programador es pensar en todo aquello que pueda salir mal (programación pesimista), no para lamentarse, sino para afrontar adecuadamente esos problemas. Es un aspecto muy ignorado en la programación, que lleva a escribir programas débiles. Las cosas no funcionan siempre como uno quisiera que funcionaran.

Comment: Hola, sigue si funcionar.
Voy a probar cambiando en fichero conf.php

`

<?php

$db_host = '//';
$db_nombre = "//";
$db_username = "//";
$db_password = "//";
$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password,$db_nombre);
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
?>

`



Este es el fichero, voy a probar a cambiarlo.

Comment: @DiPaspafe pero, ¿qué error da o qué muestra ahora el `echo json_encode($rawdata);`?

Comment: Muestra lo siguiente: **[]**, pero ya da igual. He decidido migrar mi proyecto a Express, un framework mejor y más flexible que PHP. 
Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.